# Whitespace escape when substituting one bash variable into another variable

Tags: xcode, bash, shell

I'm having trouble preserving whitespace in a bash script:

```
CURRENT_YEAR=$(date "+%Y")
MESSAGE=$(eval echo "$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print NSHumanReadableCopyright" Info.plist)")

/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set NSHumanReadableCopyright $MESSAGE" ${CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_PATH}
```

The relevant section Info.plist:

```
<NSHumanReadableCopyright>Copyright © BEC, ${CURRENT_YEAR}\nAll rights reserved.</NSHumanReadableCopyright>
```

The script reads a value from a plist, then substitutes another variable (`CURRENT_YEAR`) into the the value that was read from the plist.

The problem is that the new line in MESSAGE is causing problems. If I use `\n` then an 'n' is displayed instead of a new line. If an actual new line character is used then the command fails because 'All' is interpreted as a new command.

How do I escape the new line? Is there a better way to do this? I have very little bash-foo.

### Update - Solution:

Thanks for the help. The solution was to go crazy with quotes. Here's the finished result:

```
CURRENT_YEAR="$(date "+%Y")"
MESSAGE_TEMPLATE="$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print NSHumanReadableCopyright" Info.plist)"
MESSAGE=$(eval echo '"'"$MESSAGE_TEMPLATE"'"')
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set NSHumanReadableCopyright $MESSAGE"  ${CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_PATH}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get double-quotes around the string being `eval`'ed (so it'll substitute for the `${}` expression, but not treat the newline as a separator between commands).  This is kind of difficult, since there's no clean way to put a double-quote inside a double-quoted string; but you can do it by putting single-quoted double-quotes around the double-quoted string (oh, and then I always put double-quotes around the whole thing, even though I don't know that it's truly necessary):

```
CURRENT_YEAR=$(date "+%Y")
MESSAGE="$(eval echo '"'"$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print NSHumanReadableCopyright" Info.plist)"'"')"
```

(If you're having trouble parsing that, `'"'` is a double-quote (protected by single-quotes to keep it from being evaluated until `eval` gets it), `"$(...)"` is the result of PlistBuddy (protected by double-quotes), and then `'"'` is another protected double-quote.

After that I think your PlistBuddy Set command will work ok, but I've had to quote its values before, so just in case:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set NSHumanReadableCopyright '${MESSAGE//\'/\'}'" ${CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_PATH}
```

(what that does is put single-quotes around $MESSAGE, after escaping any embedded single-quotes.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see what `PlistBuddy` is doing well enough to know if this is the problem, but your code smells:

```
CURRENT_YEAR=$(date "+%Y")
MESSAGE=$(eval echo ...)
```

should be

```
CURRENT_YEAR="$(date "+%Y")"
MESSAGE="$(eval echo ...)"
```

(Note the **extra doublequotes around `$(...)`.**)

With luck, this will fix the problem and you can just put unescaped newlines in your file, without getting `All` interpreted as a command.  Otherwise it may be a `PlistBuddy` problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this right after the `MESSAGE=$(eval echo...` line:

```
printf -v MESSAGE "%q" "$MESSAGE"
```

That will store the value of `$MESSAGE` back to itself with characters such as `\` escaped.

Comment: This escapes all the other meta characters too which prevents eval from substituting in $CURRENT_YEAR.