# Run curl from .sh script with defined Content-Type

Tags: bash, curl, sh

When I'm trying to run test.sh script I've always receive error from curl:

```
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'application'
```

test.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
CT="Content-Type:\ application/json"

TEST="curl http://127.0.0.1 -H $CT"
echo $TEST

RESPONSE=`$TEST`
echo $RESPONSE
```

But if I just run following command from console everything fine:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1 -H Content-Type:\ application/json
```

Could you please let me know what is wrong in script, as I understand something is wrong with 'space' escape, but have no idea how to fix it.

Also I've tried following combination, but result the same:

```
CT="Content-Type: application/json"
TEST="curl http://127.0.0.1 -H \"$CT\""
```

*UPD:*

bash / dash is only available on server. (/bin/sh --> bash)

```
GNU bash, version 4.2.10(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Comment: weird... works fine for me.. add your `curl -V` output

Comment: curl 7.21.6 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.21.6 OpenSSL/1.0.0e zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.22 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL libz

Comment: Add the output of `sh --version`  and try changing `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/ksh`

Comment: Holly crap, it's bash. sh is link to bash.

Comment: GNU bash, version 4.2.10(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Comment: Yea :) On the original Unix systems, SH was a shell unto itself. Since then there've been many variations, like BASH, TCSH, CSH, SASH, KSH, DASH and so on. Most shell scripts used the link "#!/bin/sh" to make the script execute without having to specifically being called with `sh <script>`

Comment: Seems like sh is not installed on ubuntu. Only dash and bash. Unfortunatelly I have limited access to the server and can't install ksh/sh on it :(

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187614/bash-curl-eval-and-whitespace?rq=1

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Run the following: (delete the space after *Content-Type*)

```
#!/bin/bash
CT="Content-Type:application/json"

TEST="curl http://127.0.0.1 -H $CT"
echo $TEST

RESPONSE=`$TEST`
echo $RESPONSE
```

Comment: Unfortunately server doesn't agree with it :(

Comment: what the error? it's working for me.. if the error is long paste it [here](http://pastebin.com/), otherwise just write it here

Comment: @user1613658 and try swapping `#!/bin/bash` with `#!/bin/dash` and #!/bin/sh`. are you sure you don't any more shells? try `cat /etc/shells`

Comment: there is big list of 'available shells', but they are missing on file system. There are bash and dash only present. I've tried to swipe them but result the same. I'm really confused with this.

Comment: I'm confused too.. the code above worked in my bash session, and should have worked for you too.. what's the error message?

Comment: I'm sorry, had problem in json-request generation. Not it's worked fine (without space in Content-Type). Original problem relates to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3098094/whitespace-escape-when-substituting-one-bash-variable-into-another-variable

Answer (score 1):

You can try with: `bash -c your_bash_file.sh` It worked for me with the same problem